# Three.js rotating object around xyz world axis using quaternions

Tags: three.js, rotation, quaternions

I've been struggling with this for the past 3 days so here we go:

I am building a virtual photo-studio using Three.js. The rotation is set with three sliders, one for each axis. Rotation needs to happen around the world axis. So far, I can get the object to rotate around the world x axis, however, y and z rotation only happens locally. Here is the code for one of the rotation sliders using quaternions.

```js
let rotationX = new THREE.Quaternion()


sliderX.oninput = function () {

    let newVec = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0)
    let newRad = THREE.Math.degToRad(this.value)

    rotationX.setFromAxisAngle(newVec, newRad)

    pivot.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(rotationX, rotationY).multiply(rotationZ)
}
```

This approach has gotten me the farthest. The problem is that the rotation always happens around the vector of the first quaternion in the multiplication chain. That would be the quaternion "rotationX" of the following line.

```
pivot.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(rotationX, rotationY).multiply(rotationZ)
```

Because I am working with quaternions, switching around the order of multiplication is also not an option as it changes the outcome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to the dependency free repo in case you want to recreate the situation: https://github.com/maxibenner/exporter

Comment: Try `object.rotateOnWorldAxis( axis, angle )`. See the docs.

Comment: Link: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.rotateOnWorldAxis. X-axis would be a Vector3 of (1, 0, 0), y: (0, 1, 0) and z: (0, 0, 1).

Comment: I tried the rotateOnWorldAxis approach. But the problem was that it didn't work with absolute angles, meaning when I reset all the sliders, the object ends up in a completely different position than what I started with.